# convert integer to binary

Tags: python

I have an integer which I want to convert to binary and store the string of bits in an one-dimensional array starting from the right. For example, if the input is `6` then it should return an array like `[1,1,0]`. How to do it in python?

Answer (score 6):

### Solution

Probably the easiest way is not to use [`bin()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) and string slicing, but use features of [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
'{:b}'.format(some_int)
```

How it behaves:

```
>>> print '{:b}'.format(6)
110
>>> print '{:b}'.format(123)
1111011
```

In case of [`bin()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) you just get the same string, but prepended with "`0b`", so you have to remove it.

### Getting list of `int`s from binary representation

**EDIT**: Ok, so do not want just a string, but rather a list of integers. You can do it like that:

```
your_list = map(int, your_string)
```

### Combined solution for edited question

So the whole process would look like this:

```
your_list = map(int, '{:b}'.format(your_int))
```

A lot cleaner than using `bin()` in my opinion.

Comment: +1; now that `{:b}` exists, it's time to get rid of `bin(x)[2:]` abuse.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> map(int, bin(6)[2:])
[1, 1, 0]
```

If you don't want a list of ints (but instead one of strings) you can omit the `map` component and instead do:

```
>>> list(bin(6)[2:])
['1', '1', '0']
```

---

**Relevant documentation:**

- [`bin`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin)
- [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)
- [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

Comment: I wonder why use `bin()` and slicing instead of existing other options (namely binary formatting in string's `.format()`). Could you explain this choice?

Comment: @Tadeck Either method will work of course, `bin` just seemed more appropriate to me in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this command:

```
map(int, list(bin(YOUR_NUMBER)[2:]))
```

What it does is this:

- `bin(YOUR_NUMBER)` converts `YOUR_NUMBER` into its binary representation
- `bin(YOUR_NUMBER)[2:]` takes the effective number, because the string is returned in the form `'0b110'`, so you have to remove the `0b`
- `list(...)` converts the string into a list
- `map(int, ...)` converts the list of strings into a list of integers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`bin`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) function if you have Python >= 2.6:

```
list(bin(6))[2:]
```

**Edit:** oops, forgot to convert items to `int`:

```
map(int, list(bin(6))[2:])
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern Python you can (`>python2.5`):

```
>>> bin(23455)
'0b101101110011111'
```

Discard the first '0b':

```
>>> [ bit for bit in bin(23455)[2:] ]
['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

Everything together:

```
def get_bits(number):
    return [ int(bit) for bit in bin(number)[2:] ]
```

In 2.5 you will get an `NameError: name 'bin' is not defined`.

Answer (score 1):

Others answers use `bin()` for that. It works, but I find that using string operations to do mathematics is a bit... ehm... lame:

```
def tobits(x):
    r = []
    while x:
        r.append(x & 1)
        x >>= 1
    return r
```

The `tobits(0)` will return an empty list. That may be nice or not, depending on what you'll do with it. So if needed treat it as a special case.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `numpy.unpackbits`.

Here is the detailed link with examples: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html